# Height of image is not getting through jquery height() in chrome and opera

Tags: jquery, html, css, google-chrome, height

I am having a slider, in that there is a image container `li`  I am displaying `li` depends on slide timing. My issue is that if  I am finding the image height or li height at first its not displaying in chrome and opera (only some time). How to fix this issue .

**html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
<meta content="text/html; charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type">
<title>demo slider</title>
<link href="sample.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="SlideStoryHome">
<div class="slider">
        <ul class="sliderWrapper">
            <li>
                <div class="slidepart1">
                    <a href="#">
                        <img src="img/slideshow_1.jpg" alt="one" />

                    </a>
                </div>
                <div class="slidepart2">
                    demo heading
                </div>
            </li>           
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('ul.sliderWrapper li').first().addClass('active');
    var xyz = $('.sliderWrapper li').height();
    alert(xyz);

});

</script>
</body>

</html>
```

**css**

```
 ul, li,body {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    border:0;
    outline:0;
    font-size:100%;
    vertical-align:baseline;
    background:transparent;
}
.SlideStoryHome {
    float: left;
    width: 500px;
    height: auto;
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px 0px 10px 0px;
}
.slider{
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    float: left;
    background: #303030;
}
ul.sliderWrapper {
    top:0px;
    left:0px;
    margin-left: 0px;
    margin-top: 0px;
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
}
ul.sliderWrapper li {
    float: left;
    position:absolute;
    left:0px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: #303030;
    list-style: none;
}
ul.sliderWrapper li.active { position: relative; }
ul.sliderWrapper li img{
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    float: left;
}
.slidepart1{
    height: auto;
    width: 100%;
    float: left;
    background: #303030;
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.slidepart2{
    background-color:#ccc;
    background-position: left bottom;
    background-repeat: repeat-x;
    bottom: 0;
    opacity: .6;
    display: block;
    height: auto;
    left: 0;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
}
.displayNone{display: none; }
```

I am creating a filddle for this [click here](http://jsfiddle.net/randeep161/A5j4N/)

note: in the fiddle its working properly, once i copied this to my local and run through chrome or opera, then it wont.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
$(".sliderWrapper li img").load(function() {
var xyz = $('.sliderWrapper li').height();
    alert(xyz);
    })
```

Demo : http://jsfiddle.net/A5j4N/4/

Problem is :

You getting the `li` height before the `image` loaded completely

Comment: Great... Its a cool solution, its working fine, thanks rynhe :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to define the height in html body like this: [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/A5j4N/1/)

```
html,body{height: 100%;}
```

Comment: Its working only at first time, when I refresh the page its displaying height = 0.

Comment: use $(window).resize(function(){$('html,body').css('height','100%')});

Answer (score 0):

For some reason, you only get the actual height after the document is loaded and the object is displayed on the page. I have added a button and an event to check height once the button is clicked.

I have updated your fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/A5j4N/2/)

You need to get the height after the $(document) has been loaded and is ready.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#btn').click(function(){
         var xyz = $('.sliderWrapper li').height();
         alert(xyz);
    });

});
```

Comment: It will work but I cannot have a event to get the height, after getting the height I want to do a `math` calculation to display some other values.